# GIMP : Export any pictures in folder

Tags: export, bmp, gimp

first sorry for my English, I don't speak it fluently.

So, I use gimp to export my pictures in *BMP 24BIT* :

file-->export As--> select file_Type (by Extension) --> bmp --> Export --> do not write color space information (sheck) --> export

(by defaults, 24bit is sheck).

but I need to do that on 380 pictures...

Can you help me find a way to do this quickly (with a script ?)? I will be very very very grateful to you!

Comment: This is not on topic here I'm afraid. Related question on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/77429/using-gimp-to-batch-convert-images-to-another-format-in-windows

Comment: Seconded. See link for proper way using ImageMagick's `convert` or `mogrify` utilities.